# jQuery UI Draggable Dynamic Content

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm adding some dynamic content to my page when it loads. I want the rows I add to be draggable and want to be able to retrieve the value of the first `<td>` inside the `<tr>` being dragged. I've made the rows draggable, but I can't seem to retrieve the first value and I'm wondering if this is because they're added dynamically.

jQuery -

```
$(document).on('click', '.draggableJob', function() {
//draggable jobs
    $(".draggableJob").draggable({
        cursor: "move",
        cursorAt: {top: 25, left: 75},
        helper: function( event ) {
            var name = $(this).find('td').first().val();
            return $( "<div class='draggingJobHelper'>" + name + "</div>" );
          }
    });
```

HTML -

```
socket.on('loadtable', function (table) {
            $("#tableBody").append('<tr class ="draggableJob"><td>' + table["name"] +
                '</td><td>' + table["Location"] + '</td><td>' + table["Path"] + '</td><td>' + table["Foobar"] +
                '</td><td><a href="#runModal" role="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i></a>' +
                '</td><td><a href="#editModal" role="button" class="btn btn-warning edit" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i></a>'
                 + '</td><td><input type = "checkbox"></td></tr>'
            );
        });
```

Comment: i think for `<td>` you use `html()` rather than `val()` So it should be `$(this).find('td').first().html();`

Comment: Indeed you do. Nothing like JavaScript to make me feel dumb!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only use `val()` for input elements otherwise you should use `html()`

So you code should be:

```
var name = $(this).find('td').first().html();
```